# Will I see Checked Out To for myself?

Tags: check-out

We are using SharePoint 2013. I have added the column Checked Out To within a document library.

My question is, will only other users see that I have checked out a document within the Checked Out To column? In other words, I will not see if I have checked it out?

Sorry for the obvious question. I just want to make sure.

Thanks

Comment: You will see it checked out to yourself, this is pretty to test...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Checked Out To" column, you also can see that it has been checkedout to you along with other users.

Comment: How about that. Why didn't it show up the first time?

Answer (score 1):

Also note the library has a "Manage files with no checked in version" page in the library settings for uploaded files that were never checked in.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**: 
Create a view with filter as "Checked Out To " field to [Me]. This view give you desired results.

**Option 2**:
Use column filter to see your checked-out items. Click on "Checked Out To" column from list header, and select "checkout to you".